# Executing Workflow Rule in Minutes? (Time Based Workflow)

Tags: apex, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I am attempting to do a field update every 15 minutes but it seems workflow time triggers start at 1 hour. Is it possible to have workflows execute every 15 minutes?

If not, it is possible to have a countdown timer in an apex class that will execute a piece of code 15 minutes, ultimately acting like a workflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an old blog post I saved for this purpose: [The 5 minute workflow](http://sftipshack.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/the-5-minute-time-based-workflow-or-15-minute-or-30-minute/)

It will show you how to set a workflow to fire in intervals of minutes.

BUT: you cannot have it fire say every x minutes. Once a workflow fires it is done unless you reset the field and update the record. If you want something to fire every x minutes, you really should look at implementing a batch process that runs every x minutes and that itself has implications you will need to take into account

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer, an Apex class that implementing the `Schedulable` interface can do the job too.

References:

- [Apex Scheduler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm)
- Cron Expression writer - [cronmaker.com](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Example:

Write a class implementing the `Schedulable` interface

```
global class EveryFifteenMinutes implements Schedulable {
    static void doStuff(){
      // ...
    }

    public static String CronExpression = '0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *';

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        EveryFifteenMinutes.doStuff();
    }        
}
```

Then the class `EveryFifteenMinutes` needs to be scheduled.  This needs to be executed in Apex somewhere and is easily done using `Execute Anonymous` in the *Developer Console*.

Execute Anonymous:

```
String jobID = System.schedule(
    'Schedule Name', 
    EveryFifteenMinutes.CronExpression, 
    new EveryFifteenMinutes()
);
```