# Time base workflow rule trigger fire in less than 1 hour - not working

Tags: trigger, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Make time base workflow rule trigger fire in less than 1 hour

I know there is already one post on [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47239/executing-workflow-rule-in-minutes-time-based-workflow) but I have followed the instructions on that link [(this one)](https://sftipshack.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/the-5-minute-time-based-workflow-or-15-minute-or-30-minute/) and one I found online [here](http://www.buanconsulting.com/time-based-workflows-that-firein-less-than-1-hour/) but I have had no luck with it...!

The rule is definitely enabled - I have tried with 0.04145 and just 0.041 figures

Has Salesforce disabled it as these 'tricks' have been written a few years ago...?

Comment: Time based workflow does not fire to the exact minute - it runs every 15 minutes, so the field update will then be processed in the next run after it was due to fire.

Comment: @Girbot so even if I put it to a minute it still have to wait 15 minutes for it to fire as the Time-Based Workflow fires every 15minutes? Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. Say it's due to fire at 1140, the next schedule will be 1145. So the update will fire 5 minutes later than intended. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000231089&language=en_US

Comment: I've also made mention of how the workflow processor works [in this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/queued-timebase-workflow-not-firing-after-scheduled-date/77913#77913) as well. The processor does not necessarily run at 15, 30, 45, and 00 after the hour; it depends on when the server starts up.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's interesting, I was basing the times on my personal experience but that's interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my comments as an answer...

Bear in mind that time based workflow does **NOT** run to the exact minute:

> Time based workflow actions will not always execute at the exact time
>   displayed in the Monitoring setup menu. Instead, they are batched and
>   executed every 15 minutes.

Taken from this [help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000231089&language=en_US) article.

So for example if your field update is due to fire at 1140 it will be included in the next batch, due to fire at 1145.